# Create a Pick Up in Store Button that Auto fills out Shipping Address

Tags: checkout, magento-1, custom

I want to be able to click a button(pink) at "Shipping Info" to auto fill our the shipping address to my store's address.

[image]

I'm unsure how to go about this because when I select new address I can't even use jQuery to find and replace the form options with IDs.  Has anyone had experience with this?

I also don't want it to save a new address every time and if possible I want to do this without using or buying an extension!

Comment: Can this one suit your needs? http://www.rapidcommerce.eu/en/blog/2012/07/magento-store-pickup/

Comment: No, at shipping address I calculate what tax needs to be paid based on their region/area of purchase. I literally want to click this button at checkout and it enters their shipping address to my actual physical store's address.

Comment: hey did you get this?